# "Is not defined" error trying to read database with nodejs and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I can read the database and render it in the file **mascotas.ejs** but can't do it in the file **index.ejs**, it throw an error "arrayMascotas is not defined".

For the database I'm using mongoDB, also I'm using ejs templates and express.

Sorry if I didn't explain something correctly, it's my first web using mongoDB and probably is a small thing but I've trying resolve it during hours.

The idea is to read and render the data from mongodb into a table, in **mascotas.ejs** is working but not in **index.ejs**

**mascotas.ejs**

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">a</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% if(arrayMascotas.length > 0) { %>
                        <% arrayMascotas.forEach(mascota => { %>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><%= mascota.id %></th>
                                <td><%= mascota.a %></td>
                              </tr>
                        <% }) %>
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**index.ejs**

```
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">name</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <% if(arrayMascotas.length > 0) { %>
                                <% arrayMascotas.forEach(mascota => { %>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><%= mascota.state %></td>
                                      </tr>
                                <% }) %>
                            <% } %>        
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

**app.js**

```
app.use("/", require("./router/Rutasweb"));
app.use("/mascotas", require("./router/Mascotas"));
```

**Mascotas.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Mascota = require("../models/mascota")

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        
        const arrayMascotasDB = await Mascota.find()
        console.log(arrayMascotasDB)

        res.render("mascotas", {
            arrayMascotas: arrayMascotasDB
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You show where you define the variable for `Mascotas.js`, but show nothing for `index.js` (or `Rutasweb.js`?).  Do you define the variable there?  If not, that's why it's not defined.

Comment: Should I add it on app.js?

Comment: Probably not, given the information shown.  Where is `index.ejs` rendered?  The last code snippet shown demonstrates the rendering of "mascotas", but where is the rendering of "index"?

Comment: I think thats a perfect point to start reviewing, Im changing "mascotas" per "/" or "index" and still not working. But thanks a lot David!